# Tex markup, how to render it in Html with Python?

Tags: python, html, tex

The *Tex markup* support has been recently [added](https://cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3/latex-math-support) to the following Stack Exchange sites:

- [Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/)
- [Statistical Analysis](https://stats.stackexchange.com/)
- [Theoretical Computer Science](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/)

These sites are using the client side [Mathjax](http://www.mathjax.org/demos/tex-samples/) library to correctly format the submitted formulas to the user.

Since this new feature was added, the [StackExchange API](https://stackapps.com/questions/1/api-documentation-and-help) returns the JSON question/answers text with formulas delimited by the `$` char Tex Markup ([here](http://api.cstheory.stackexchange.com/1.0/questions/2347?body=True&comments=True&pagesize=1) an example).
[StackPrinter](http://www.stackprinter.com), built on this API, merely prints the returned text full of $ with an [orrible result](http://www.stackprinter.com/export?format=HTML&service=cstheory.stackexchange&printer=false&question=2347).

I'm searching for a server side Python library that can parse and trasform the JSON Data to properly render the Tex Markup in Html.
Do you know any solution?

Application details:
Platform: [Google App Engine](http://code.google.com/appengine/)
Framework: [webpy](http://webpy.org/)

Comment: Why not including Mathjax in your html pages as stackexchange does?

Comment: yes, it's an option but I would like to know if exist a possible solution server side (probably not for the fonts problem).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try combining a TeX-to-DVI tool (such as [tex.latex2dvi](http://packages.python.org/tex/) or [pytex](http://www.pytex.org/)) with a DVI-to-image tool (such as [dvipng](http://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/dvipng/)). To implement this on the server side, you would need an API endpoint that takes TeX code as input and serves an image as output. This way, you can render math formulas as images by pointing their source to that URL, with the corresponding parameters. This is quite complex, but the good news is that [Google Chart API for math formulas](http://code.google.com/intl/es/apis/chart/docs/gallery/formulas.html) already provides such service.

Anyway, I would consider using [MathML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MathML#Embedding_MathML_in_HTML5_files) to render math notation on the client side, since all major web browsers (except Internet Explorer) support this feature in compliance with HTML5 standards. Or just including Mathjax like StackExchange (this is client-side markup rendering too). This seems the most simple and cross-platform alternative.

Comment: MathML has its own pitfalls — trying to find the right combination of doctype and MIME type and other browser sniffing triggers for your page to even **load**, let alone render consistently across browsers, can be difficult — if it's even possible.