# How to use MathJax library on Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, tex, mathjax

I'm trying to add Tex support to my application and I would like to use [MathJax](http://www.mathjax.org/) to render Mathematics formulas client side since I gave up the 
server side solution explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4592501/tex-markup-how-to-render-it-in-html-with-python).
The MathJax library is pretty fat (30.000 files) and it can't be easily installed on App Engine due to the [files number limitation](http://code.google.com/intl/it-IT/appengine/docs/python/runtime.html#Quotas_and_Limits).

I have no experience with MathJax library so I'm open to other strategies like:

- Available MathJax CDN
- Cutting down some directories/files to reduce the package's files number.

Do you know any way to use Mathjax on Google App Engine?

Comment: downloading mathjax now just to see why they use 30,000 files!  i assume it's something to do with the fonts/glyphs?

Comment: wow.  yeah, there appear to be separate png's for each symbol/leter/number etc... per font.  Those might only be used as backup when a browser can't handle the "better" solutions involving actual fonts.  you could try deleting the "fonts\HTML-CSS\TeX\png\" folder and see if stuff still works in most browsers...

Comment: @Peter thanks for your time, I tried your solution and it does fit on Gae.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use http://mathjax.connectmv.com : we are not a CDN, but we publicly host the most recent MathJax files for free.

We have expire headers set at 2 weeks and `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` to allow for cross-site access.

Comment: so far, so good. Demo using connectmv.com [here](http://1d.latest.stackprinter.appspot.com/export?question=164&format=HTML&service=math.stackexchange&linktohome=false&printer=false)

Answer (score 6):

Since March 2011 [MathJAX has its own CDN](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/start.html), so you can now use it without uploading any files to GAE.  Just make sure this is in any page's header:

```
<script type="text/javascript" async
  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.0/MathJax.js?...">
</script>
```

Comment: For me it required `?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML` suffixed to the URL, as suggested in the MathJax [Getting Started](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/start.html) section.

Comment: @BobStein-VisiBone: Thanks for the amendment.  I've added the query string.

Comment: You're welcome, @MatthewLeingang. Reformatting to your liking? If not please revert.

Comment: This is very helpful.  Too bad this does not work well for https.

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check https://www.mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down/ for migration tips.

Answer (score 2):

If you delete the png file, be sure to set the imageFont value to null in the configuration, so that MathJax will not try to use the image fonts.  Peter is correct, they are for use with browsers that don't handle @font-face CSS directives (this includes iPhone/iTouch/iPad, though iOS4.2 now handles it properly and MathJax should soon handle that), but are also used for Firefox when MathJax is loaded from a local file (a file:// URL) that is not in the same directory or a subdirectory of the one containing the HTML file that loaded it.  If you are not in either of those situations, it is safe to remove the image fonts.

Comment: I removed the image fonts directory and set the imageFont to null. It seems to wait for some timeout on Firefox 3.6.13+OSX 10.5.8 when it has to download the webfonts, Chrome 9.0 is doing the same, Safari is pretty good. Tried on FF 3.6 on Windows XP and it works smoothly. Demo [here](http://1c.latest.stackprinter.appspot.com/export?question=3405&format=HTML&service=math.stackexchange&linktohome=false&printer=false)

Comment: You could just reference the copy of MathJax at www.mathjax.org rather than loading it yourself.  We are also setting up a CDN for MathJax, but that isn't quite ready yet.

Comment: The FF 3.6.13 introduced a stricter font analyzer, and MathJax's origin OTF fonts didn't pass its inspection.  I see you are using v1.0.1; have you updated the fonts to the new set that works with FF 3.6.13?  See http://www.mathjax.org/download/ for details. I checked FF 3.6.8, and it worked fine, so I suspect that you have not updated the fonts to the new OTF fonts that work with FF 3.6.13.

Comment: It looks like you didn't load the SVG fonts in the fonts/HTML-CSS/TeX directory.  If you only moved the OTF, that will not be enough.  You need to SVG and EOT directories as well.  The only one you can eliminate is the PNG directory.  Chrome uses the SVG fonts, so if they are missing, that would account for the slowness of Chrome, since it will wait for a timeout for the fonts before continuing.

Comment: thanks for your help, I've opted for the connectmv.com solution that does fit better on Google App Engine.